# nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query - "0_" added

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm new in Hybernate, so sorry if it is stupid quesiton.
When I'm running JUnit Test, I see this error:

```
could not execute query; SQL [select employee0_.id_employee as id_emplo1_5_, employee0_.date_of_birth as date_of_2_5_, employee0_.id_department as id_depar9_5_, employee0_.email as email3_5_, employee0_.home_phone as home_pho4_5_, employee0_.mobile_phone as mobile_p5_5_, employee0_.name as name6_5_, employee0_.pesel as pesel7_5_, employee0_.surname as surname8_5_ from employee employee0_]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Hibernate is adding some "0_" to query? I have this columns in my mysql db.

**My EmployeeDAO has:**

```
    public List<Employee> findEmployeeByDepartmentName(String name) {
        TypedQuery<Employee> query = entityManager.createQuery(
                "select e from Employee e join e.department  d where d.name = :name",
                Employee.class);
        query.setParameter("name", name);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

and Employe:

```
package com.capgemini.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
```

//more imports...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long idEmployee;

    @Column(nullable = true, length = 30)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = true, length = 30)
    private String surname;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 11)
    private BigInteger pesel;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 10, columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 10)
    private BigDecimal homePhone;

    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 9)
    private BigDecimal mobilePhone;

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
//more getters....

    public void setIdEmployee(Long idEmployee) {
        this.idEmployee = idEmployee;
    }
//more setters...


}
```

What can be the reason of this eroor?
I simplified my question as much as possible.

Comment: I would grab the sql statement and execute it in a utility. It will tell you the error then you can fix the DAO

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the extra things Hibernate adds to your query, those are just alias names it auto generates (and the numbers ensure they're unique).

Your query is simply not correct, so look for errors here:

```
select e from Employee e join e.department  d where d.name = :name
```

Remember that this is not SQL, but HQL which is subtly different.

First thing I noticed is that the `Employee` class has no field called `department`, so I would check that first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so soorry! I pasted wronge method/code:

```
@Override
public List<Employee> findEmployeeByName(String name) {
    TypedQuery<Employee> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT e FROM Employee e where e.name like :name",
            Employee.class);
    query.setParameter("name", name);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

And Eroor:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [select employee0_.id_employee as id_emplo1_5_, employee0_.date_of_birth as date_of_2_5_, employee0_.id_department as id_depar9_5_, employee0_.email as email3_5_, employee0_.home_phone as home_pho4_5_, employee0_.mobile_phone as mobile_p5_5_, employee0_.name as name6_5_, employee0_.pesel as pesel7_5_, employee0_.surname as surname8_5_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.name like ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Even if I simplify it:

```
@Override
public List<Employee> findEmployeeByName(String name) {
    TypedQuery<Employee> query = entityManager.createQuery(
            "SELECT e FROM Employee e",
            Employee.class);
    query.setParameter("name", name);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

The error is:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [select employee0_.id_employee as id_emplo1_5_, employee0_.date_of_birth as date_of_2_5_, employee0_.id_department as id_depar9_5_, employee0_.email as email3_5_, employee0_.home_phone as home_pho4_5_, employee0_.mobile_phone as mobile_p5_5_, employee0_.name as name6_5_, employee0_.pesel as pesel7_5_, employee0_.surname as surname8_5_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.name like ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

I executed this query in Workbench (deleting 0_) and it is working:

```
use mytestdb;
select employee.id_employee as id_emplo1_5_, employee.date_of_birth as date_of_2_5_, employee.id_department as id_depar9_5_, employee.email as email3_5_, employee.home_phone as home_pho4_5_, employee.mobile_phone as mobile_p5_5_, employee.name as name6_5_, employee.pesel as pesel7_5_, employee.surname as surname8_5_ from employee employee
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I change

```
@Column(name = "dateOfBirth", nullable = false, length = 10, columnDefinition = "DATE")
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
```

to

```
@Column(name = "dateOfBirth", nullable = false, length = 10, columnDefinition = "DATE")
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

Then it is working! Why? How can I fix it?